# Passing variable to WP header via PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

On WP sites I normally pass variables to the header like this:

SINGLE.PHP:

```
       global $x;
       $x = "y";
       get_header();
```

HEADER.PHP

```
       global $x;         
       var_dump($x);
```

This works great normally. But I have one site on a multisite installation where it always dumps "NULL" - even though every other site on the multisite will dump "y". I have reduced both files just to the above code, and still get "NULL". Can anyone suggest what might be the issue please?!

Comment: Please clarify where/how exactly you are "getting NULL." Trying to output a NULL value with echo will only result in "nothing", an empty string being output. So if you are actually _seeing_ "NULL" anywhere, it can hardly be from the code as shown.

Comment: Yep, sorry - have edited my question - I was doing var_dump, not echo.

Comment: Then something must probably have overwritten the variable value somewhere - in a hook/filter that gets executed by get_header maybe. Do things change if you use a different variable name?

Comment: Thanks for your replies btw... No - I've tried several different variable names, including nonsense unikely to be used in any other code, and it always produces NULL. Interesting point though - I suppose it could be a plug-in not used on other sites that is doing something to the header somehow...